# How to add iAd banner programmatically in landscape in sprite kit swift

Tags: ios, swift, iad, skscene

Does anyone know how to add an iAd banner programmatically? I am making a game using Sprite Kit and Swift. The game is in Landscape mode. Any help would be much appreciated.

I'm using SKScene's, not ViewControllers fyi.

I also tried this code :

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController, ADBannerViewDelegate {

var adBannerView: ADBannerView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Presenting scene without using GameScene.sks
    let skView = self.view as SKView
    let myScene = Menu(size: skView.frame.size)
    skView.presentScene(myScene)

    loadAds()

}

func bannerViewActionShouldBegin(banner: ADBannerView!, willLeaveApplication willLeave: Bool) -> Bool {
    println("Leaving app to the Ad")

    return true
}

func bannerViewDidLoadAd(banner: ADBannerView!) {

    adBannerView.center = CGPoint(x: adBannerView.center.x, y: view.bounds.size.height - adBannerView.frame.size.height / 2)
    adBannerView.frame = CGRectOffset(adBannerView.frame,0.0,0.0)
    adBannerView.hidden = false


    println("Displaying the Ad")
}


func bannerView(banner: ADBannerView!, didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: NSError!) {

    adBannerView.center = CGPoint(x: adBannerView.center.x, y: view.bounds.size.height + view.bounds.size.height)
    println("Ad is not available")
}


func loadAds() {
    adBannerView = ADBannerView(frame: CGRect.zeroRect)
    adBannerView.frame = CGRectOffset(adBannerView.frame,0,0.0)
    adBannerView.delegate = self
    adBannerView.hidden = true
    view.addSubview(adBannerView)
}
```

This presents the add on the bottom of the screen but with the height and width as if it was in portrait mode, I need the add to be shown using the full width of the landscape mode and less heigh.

Comment: Check out this post, it's in Obj-C but you could translate it. http://codewithchris.com/iad-tutorial/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code might solve your question:

```
let screenBounds: CGRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds

var adBannerView: ADBannerView  
adBannerView = ADBannerView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, screenBounds.width))
adBannerView.center = CGPoint(x: screenBounds.width/2, y: screenBounds.height-adBannerView.frame.height)
adBannerView.delegate = self
adBannerView.hidden = true
view.addSubview(adBannerView)
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Hm, I appreciate the help Linus. Unfortunately it is still doing the same exact thing. It shows the banner at the bottom with the same width and height as if the scene would be in portrait mode. However again, mine needs to be in landscape. I appreciate the help though. Do you know what might be wrong ?

Comment: Now the banner is centered, but still only as wide as it would be in portrait mode and as high as it would be in portrait mode.

Comment: Do you switch between landscape and portrait mode?

Comment: So you do even start in landscape mode? Please print the screenBounds for me. height & width

Comment: Yes. I just copied your code and switched it with mine in loadAds( ).There's nothing else that has changed from the code I posted in my initial post.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73688/discussion-between-linus-g-and-miles-h).

Comment: What was the resolution?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
    var UIiAd: ADBannerView = ADBannerView()

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

    UIiAd.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
    UIiAd.delegate = self
    self.view.addSubview(UIiAd)
    let viewsDictionary = ["bannerView":UIiAd]
    view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|[bannerView]|", options: .allZeros, metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary))
    view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:[bannerView]|", options: .allZeros, metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary))

    }
```